# Implementing dependency injection using Vue and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, dependency-injection, vuejs2

I tried using vue-injector but it compile with my version of Vue (2.6.10) and Typescript (3.4.5).

I see very few other options.

On the pure typescript side I see things like Inversify and TSyringe which look good but don't work with Vue out of the box.

This is inversify:

```
Argument of type typeof App' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
      Type 'typeof App' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.
        Types of parameters 'authService' and 'options' are incompatible.
          Type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'AuthService': app, scopes, login, logout, getAccount
```

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  constructor(
    @inject(AuthService) authService: AuthService
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

I assume I need to create a class with the correct signature but before I disappear down that rabbit hole, does anyone have any experience with Vue/Typescript/DI and could point me in the direction of a sensible solution?

Answer (score 0):

`inject`, etc. decorators cannot be used with component class. The use of decorators assumes that the class is instantiated by Inversify injector, while component class is instantiated by Vue framework, so a parameter that is provided to component constructor won't be an instance of `AuthService`. This is what type error warns about.

The same problem is applicable to React components or any other framework that doesn't use Inversify internally.

Inversify container should be accessed manually:

```
authService: AuthService = container.get(AuthService)
```

Since [Vue already provides DI](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject), it may be more convenient to use its own DI instead of third-party library like Inversify.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject:
provide and inject are primarily provided for advanced plugin / component library use cases. It is NOT recommended to use them in generic application code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this one [vue-injector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@scandltd/vue-injector)